# Cmd findstr if folder name matches regex

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I have a real simple question. In a batch file I have the following:

`echo %Axx% | >nul findstr /r /c:"^A[0-9]{6}" || ( echo "true" )
pause >nul`

`%Axx%` is in the format `A123456`. But it doesn't echo "true".
Am I not using the right regex, or is it something else? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findstr`'s regex capabilities are very limited.

Try "^A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

or `findstr /b /r /c:"A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"`

Comment: Thank you, your first solution worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no count `{}` in `findstr` expressions -- type `findstr /?` into a command prompt window and see the very limited possibilities.

To match a certain number of characters or expressions, you need to repeat the respective search expression, like this:

```
echo(%Axx%| > nul findstr /R /C:"^A[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]$" && echo true
> nul pause
```

If you want to match the whole string exactly, you need to append `$`. Additionally, you must remove the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the pipe symbol `|`, because it was also echoed otherwise.

I am using `[0123456789]` rather than `[0-9]` in the search expression, because the former matches numerals only, but the latter may match some special characters like `²` or `³` also, depending on the current code page.

Note that `/B` is the same as `^` as the first character in the search string, so do not state both.

Finally, I believe you actually want to echo `true` in case `%Axx%` matches the search string. That is why I replaced `||` by `&&`. If I am wrong and you want the inverted behaviour, just keep `||`.